# how to log Nodejs Debug Log into a single place in case of scalable architecture set up using Load Balancer

Tags: node.js, cloud, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have a NodeJs based scalable architecture, I want to log all the logs into single place. But in case load balancing, system logs will be scattered to multiple VMs.And I will loose the logs once VM scale down How to solve this issues?

How can I log all logs from all the scaled VMs in instance group into single place.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - use Stackdriver Logging, which is intended for this exact purpose!  https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs